# How to align right this long table?

Tags: longtable

I have a longtable. This is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{answers}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{cauhoi}{Quetion}
\Newassociation{ans}{Soln}{hint}
\renewcommand{\Solnlabel}[1]{{\bf  Answer #1}.}

\newenvironment{point}{%
\par\noindent
\begin{longtable}[t]{|p{14cm}|p{1.2cm}|}

\hline
}{%
\end{longtable}
}
\newcommand\diem[1]{ & \hfil \textbf{#1} \\ \hline}
\newcommand\tongdiem[1]{\dotfill [\textbf{#1} points]}
%\newcommand\tongdiem[1]{\fill [\textbf{#1} điểm]}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{16truept}
\Opensolutionfile{hint}[ans] 

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
QUESTIONS
\end{center}
\begin{cauhoi}%1
(2 points) Find the domain of definition of the function \begin{equation*}
y = \sqrt{x^2 - 3x + 2} + \dfrac{1}{x + 4}.
\end{equation*}
\begin{ans}\tongdiem{2.5}
\begin{point}
First \diem{1}

This is 
\diem{1.0}

Second
\diem{0.5}

\end{point}
\end{ans}
\end{cauhoi}


\begin{cauhoi}%2
(2 points) Solve the equation \begin{equation*}
\sqrt{x + 1} + \sqrt{x + 2}-\sqrt{x + 3} =5.
\end{equation*}
\begin{ans}\tongdiem{2.5}
\begin{point}
First \diem{1}

Second
\diem{1.0}

Thirt
\diem{0.5}

\end{point}
\end{ans}
\end{cauhoi}


\vfill
\noindent \hrulefill

\Closesolutionfile{hint}
\newpage
\begin{center}
\large\textbf{ANSWER}
\end{center}
\Readsolutionfile{hint}

\end{document}
```

I want the out put has the form. Please help me.
[image]

Comment: don't use `\noindent` before `longtable`: it just causes a blank white line to be inserted before the table along with spurious parskip vertical space, and if you are unlucky, a bad page break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the both the sides aligned using:

```
\begin{longtable}[t]{|p{14cm}|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-14cm-3\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}@{}|}
```

[image]

This computes the required width of the right column so as to fill it.

If you just want to alignit on the right you can use the optional paraamter of `longtable` to specify that the table is to be `r`ight aligned:

```
\begin{longtable}[r]{|p{14cm}|p{1.2cm}|}
```

[image]

### Notes:

- The `[showframe]` option to [the `geometry` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) was used so that we could see the page margins.
  was used just to show the page margins.
- Another option would be to use [the `tabularx` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) which allows for `X` column types that can expand to fill the specified width.
- Further more you should have a look at [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) for more professional looking tables.
- As Marco Daniel commented, you should also have a look at the [the `ltxtable` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable) which
  provides the functionality of `longtable` and `tabularx` together inside a `longtable` environment.

Comment: Small hint: The optional argument of the environment `longtable` specify the horizontal alignment. Allowed parameter are: `c`, `l` and `r`. And I think `ltxtable` should be mentioned here.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Thanks. I did not read that as an option, but you are correct the question does not specify whether the alinement is to just be on the right, or on both sides, which is what I had interpreted.

Comment: just a small remark: in the argument `[r]` no spaces are allowed for proper function, like <strike>`[ r ]`</strike>